# Mathematica does not respect linearity of integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, regions

Fixed in **11.3**

---

I have the following issue, trying to evaluate an integral. Mathematica tells me

```
Integrate[x^2 (1 + x^2)^(1/2) + y + z, {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]

(* 1/2 π (3 Sqrt[2] - Log[2 (2 + Sqrt[2])]) *)
```

By the way, it also gives me

```
Integrate[x^2 (1 + x^2)^(1/2), {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]

(* 1/4 π (6 Sqrt[2] + Log[3 - 2 Sqrt[2]]) *)
```

And, of course,

```
Integrate[y + z, {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]

(* 0 *)
```

You can check that the two results are not equal (they differ by $\frac{3\pi}{8}\log 2$); therefore the linearity of the integral is not respected. How can I explain this fact?

Thank you in advance! This is really puzzling me up.

Comment: Same behavior here on Mathematica 11.0.1 on macos 10.12.6. I would classify that as a bug. Note that this does not happen with `NIntegrate` which has some other issues instead.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. By the way, do you know what is the bug caused by? So that one can at least try to avoid it.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Personally, I mostly avoid everything provided by Mathematica related to two dimensional `MeshRegions`; mostly for the reason that many features haven't been implemented yet. But this issue is really striking. Would you please be so kind and send a bug report to Wolfram Research?

Comment: Same behavior for 11.2 on Windows 10.  Bug.

Comment: Under linux, 10.3.0 gives the correct result, but 11.0.0 does not.

Comment: Thank you to everybody. By the way, also the incorrect result is interesting... that 3\[Pi]/8 Log[2] must mean something at least for the computing algorithm: I wonder what that means!

Comment: Work with `Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1]` to see, that the first two solutions are wrong. Result is `(11 \[Pi])/(12 Sqrt[2]) - 3/8 \[Pi] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]` (Done with MMA Version 8.0).

Comment: Akku14 you are integrating over the ball, not on the sphere. Actually for some reason Mathematica does not show any problem when integrating in full-dimension submanifold as, for example, the ball.

Comment: confirm it is fixed in 11.3  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lRDuy.png)

Answer (score 11):

This is a bug introduced in 10.4.0 and persisting through 11.2.0.  It is already fixed in our internal development build, so it should be fixed in our next release.

I haven't tracked down the cause, but based on the different answers over various versions, it is probably either a simplification bug, or a branch cut issue.

Comment: Upvoting for saving me the time tracking down the actual cause...